# How can I sync two observables?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a an observable of type any in a class and I need to use it in a component.

I have an observable in my class and a method to update this observable using an http request.

```
export class BusquedaService {
  resultados$: Observable<any>;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  buscar( termino: string ) {
    this.resultados$ = this.http.get(`${environment.urlAPI}/products?&name=${termino}`).pipe(
      map( (data : any) => {
        return data.products;
      })
    );
  }
}
```

I have a component where I need to use this observable and read its value.

```
export class BusquedaComponent implements OnInit {
  resultados$: Observable<any>;
  constructor(private busquedaService: BusquedaService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.resultados$ = this.busquedaService.resultados$;
  }
}
```

So in this component I declare an observable of type any and in `ngOnInit()` I asign the value of the observable in the service to it. The problem is that this value (the variable inside the component) doesn't update.

I can declare the service as public in my component in order to use it on the HTML, but I wonder if there is a way to do this in a similar way I'm trying.

How can I do this?

Comment: what does `this value doesn't update` mean? what do you expect and what happens instead?

Comment: Where is your `subscribe()` call on the `Observable`?

Comment: @TimKlein - probably async pipe in the template.

Comment: You need to subscribe() or use async pipe to get HttpClient calls actually execute. Also change it to `this.resultados$ = this.busquedaService.buscar(whateverQuery);` or `this.busquedaService.buscar(whateverQuery).subcribe(result => { do whatever with response })`

Comment: You never call the `this.busquedaService.buscar` method so `this.busquedaService.resultados$` will be undefined when you assign that to `this.resultados$:` in `BusquedaComponent`. Why not follow along with the tutorial on the https://angular.io web site? That will answer a lot of questions for you and give a some good examples on how to create interactions between components and services.

Comment: I have written a library ngx-rxcache that helps you with managing Angular state like this. Have a read of my article at https://medium.com/@adrianbrand/angular-state-management-with-rxcache-468a865fc3fb